# select multiple sections of a string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string, match

I'm trying to slice up a string and having trouble.

In rails, I have a very long string, and in it, something like this occurs 3-6 times:

```
bunchofotherstringstuffandcharacters"hisquote":"The most important aspect of the painting was the treatment of lighting.","lp":andthenalotmorestringandcharacters
```

I want to slice out "The most important aspect of the painting was the treatment of lighting.", and also other instances that fall between hisquote and lp.

The "hisquote" that comes before it is unique to the strings I want, and so is the .","lp that comes after it

How can I get back all the instances of the strings between these two identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something like this?  I'm assuming that your delimiters `:` and `,` are consistent throughout the string, as well as the use of double quotes `"` to enclose the desired strings.

```
# escape double quotes
longstring = %q(bunchofotherstringstuffandcharacters"hisquote":"The most important aspect of the painting was the treatment of lighting.","lp":andthenalotmorestringandcharacters)

# split on double quotes
substrings = longstring.split("\"").to_enum

# somewhere to sure the strings you want
save = []

# use a rescue clause to detect that the enumerator 'substrings' as reached an end
begin
    while true do
        remember = substrings.next
        case substrings.peek # lets see if that next element is our deliminator
        when ":" # Once the semicolon is spotted ahead, grab the three strings we want.
            save << remember
            substrings.next # skip the ":"
            save << substrings.next
            substrings.next # skip the ","
            save << substrings.next
        end
    end
rescue StopIteration => e
    puts "End of Substring Enumeration was reached."
ensure
    puts save.inspect   #=>  ["hisquote", "The most important aspect of the painting was the treatment of lighting.", "lp"]
end
```

Comment: I think it's trickier, because the "bunchofotherstringstuffandcharacters" is actually full of every type of character - quotes, slashes, colons...everything. For example: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"> <head> <title> - as you can see, it's html content. But, the delimiters noted, "hisquote": and .","lp are unique

Comment: Having a hard time getting these down right - it is, hisquote":"

That is, the words hisquote followed by a double quote mark, then a colon, then another double quote mark - this is the unique delimiter on the front of the wanted strings

Comment: Ok, so by saying `"hisquote":"` and `.","lp` are unique, you mean to say that within the long string, the text that you need is always between these two delimiters?  Also are you sure its not `.","lp"` with the trailing doublequote?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean - within the long string, the text that I need is always between those two delimiters. About the second delimiter, ,"."lp is a sufficiently unique delimiter, however it turns out all those instances do indeed have a double quote following them. So, the second delimiter could just as well be, ,"."lp"

Thanks for taking a look at this @freemasonjson!

Comment: Got it all now, it works. The key thing in your answer was "split", which let me work on breaking things up the right way. (Was wrestling with which of match, scan, regexp, or other tools to use). Thank you!

Comment: okay cool, yeah lol `split` is one of my best buddies, although you may run into issues with performance.